# Why did UIImageView did not load properly using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, iboutlet, viewdidload

basically I want to create road where hero will move on before game starts, so user can see his first steps, but the problem is that when I post code in `override func viewDidLoad` it only load image appearance what I post in `Main.storyboard` not that code,using `print` it shows that images are in place them need to be, but that's not what I see on screen. In alternative, I place same code in `@IBAction func play` and after I press play button images load as them need to be.**Here are code that I put in viewDidLoad:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var hero: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var bigroad: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var road: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var roadTwo: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var play: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     self.play.hidden = false
     self.hero.hidden = false
     self.bigroad.hidden = false
     self.road.hidden = false
     self.roadTwo.hidden = false

     self.hero.center.x = (width / 2) + 3
     self.hero.center.y = ((height / 2.5) + (height / 3.5)) - 46
     self.bigroad.center = CGPointMake(width / 2 , (height / 2.5) + (height / 3.5))
     self.road.center = CGPointMake(width / 2  + 39, (height / 2.5) + (height / 3.5) - 29)
     self.roadTwo.center = CGPointMake((width / 2 ) + 78, ((height / 2.5) + (height / 3.5)) - 58)
```

As I said, when I put his same code in `@IBAction func play` and when func play starts everything is in place.
**My question is why images didn't load in place were them need to be in viewDidLoad, but loads perfectly in play function? What Do I do wrong and how can I prevent my mistake?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your frame code to point, when all autolayout processes are finished. For example:

```
var layedOut = false

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if !layedOut {
        // perform your frame code
        self.hero.center.x = (width / 2) + 3
        self.hero.center.y = ((height / 2.5) + (height / 3.5)) - 46
        self.bigroad.center = CGPointMake(width / 2 , (height / 2.5) + (height / 3.5))
        self.road.center = CGPointMake(width / 2  + 39, (height / 2.5) + (height / 3.5) - 29)
        self.roadTwo.center = CGPointMake((width / 2 ) + 78, ((height / 2.5) + (height / 3.5)) - 58)
    }
}
```

Note that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` can be called multiple times, so you need catch point when all is already on screen and disable frame initialization code in this method, with flag for example

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    layedOut = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    layedOut = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
weak var
```

Outlets are not loaded, try to do that on viewWillAppear() It is just too soon to do that on viewDidLoad()

Comment: wrong. outlets loaded, viewWillAppear will give same result

Comment: If the outlets were not loaded, he would crash on `self.play.hidden` because of the `!` on `play: UIButton!`.